# handling 2 Firebase values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

having the following Firebase structure:

```
Node
  val1:20
  val2:30
```

how to get val1 + val2 as a function return ? and how to create a promise or Observable for firebase object?

Comment: The Firebase Database doesn't have operators to return aggregate values. If you need the sum of two values, you either have to store that sum (and update it on writes) or calculate it client side.

Comment: well, I find a way by using new Promis to fix this issue

Comment: Good to hear. Promises are one great tool to use when implementing client-side aggregation.